# Like counter - bare number

Tags: php, facebook

I'd like to use facebook api for getting likes number (and only number). As I've learnt, I need to use url like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27URL%27
```

Okay, it does present some data, but how to use it? How to include it on my website the most effectively? Do i have to use file_get_contents, which I found out is quite slow?

Please, let me know what are your solutions.

Pawel

Comment: file_get_contents() then json_decode() the response to start with

Comment: Use `cURL` to get the response and `json_decode()` to parse it and get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```
<?php
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=';
$query = "SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id in(SELECT page_id, type FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me() AND type != 'APPLICATION' )&access_token=". $facebook->getAccessToken();
$ch = curl_init(urlencode($query));
$ch = $url.$ch;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's the guidance I needed :)